# How To Combine MySQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a database called 'mylist'. In it tables exists as 'list1' 'list2' 'list3'. All tables contain same structure and column names however data is different.

If I have to select all data from all tables then what query should I run ?

Comment: Please show your effort. This is not a site “write a code for me.”

Comment: @mudasobwa  ... Being not expert in MySql I asked for a single query. I used JOIN function but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using UNION among all of them to get all the rows like below:

```
SELECT output.mycol1, output.mycol2
FROM
(SELECT list1.mycol1, list1.mycol2
FROM list1
UNION
SELECT list2.mycol1, list2.mycol2
FROM list2
UNION
SELECT list3.mycol1, list3.mycol2
FROM list3) AS "output"
ORDER BY output.mycol1
```

Comment: Thank You Sir !! 
It will work using while loop in PHP....

But how to ORDER BY 'timex' DESC all ?

Comment: And now change UNION to UNION ALL and you'll get the result much faster (unless you really have/need DISTINCT data)